# Selecting value from dropdownlist gives error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webmethod

I have set of code which fills my `dropdownlist`. So when I select some value from the list it works fine,

But when I go to the default selection which is `--Select--` I get error as

> the source contains no datarows

and it goes to the `catch` part

Below is my code. I Know I am missing something. Please suggest how to handle this

```
[WebMethod]
    public static MaintDetails[] GetMaintZone(string ddlState)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<MaintDetails> details = new List<MaintDetails>();

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["dtStateMZ"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["dtStateMZ"];

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("JIOSTATECODE") == ddlState).CopyToDataTable();
                    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            MaintDetails MZone = new MaintDetails();
                            MZone.MAINTID = dtrow["MAINTENANCEZONECODE"].ToString();
                            MZone.MAINTNAME = dtrow["MAINTENANCEZONENAME"].ToString();
                            details.Add(MZone);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills: this line `dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("JIOSTATECODE") == ddlState).CopyToDataTable();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with these lines:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("JIOSTATECODE") == ddlState).CopyToDataTable();
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
```

The `CopyToDataTable` line is throwing the exception since it was called with (effectively) 0 rows. The solution, then, is to ensure that doesn't happen:

```
var bob = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("JIOSTATECODE") == ddlState).ToList();
if (bob.Count > 0)
{
    dt = bob.CopyToDataTable();
```

The above code copies the data into a temporary `List`, then ensures there is data in the `List` **before** calling `CopyToDataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a check for `ddlState` as well. When you perform a check to see if you have a session variable, also check if the `ddlState` is not a default value, like

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["dtStateMZ"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ddlState) && ddlState != "0")
{
    // your logic here
}

return details.ToArray();
```

That should prevent your code from failing. The problem is in the line:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("JIOSTATECODE") == ddlState).CopyToDataTable();
```

It could be that `CopyToDataTable` does not check the input value, that is, whether it is null or empty, and it tries to work on it. This will cause a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown.

If you want to be on a safe side, add `try..catch` block and return an empty array in the catch block.

#### Update

Considering that you are receiving `0` for `ddlState` and that would not return any result, check to see if your string is equal to "0". If it is don't go into the `if` part, but skip over it.

Comment: True, I am working with JavaScript at the moment, and just typed !== instead of !=. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: I've added `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` instead of `!=`, just so that you are on the safe side with various string possibilities.

Comment: even after adding that condition, It gets into catch at this line `dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("JIOSTATECODE") == ddlState).CopyToDataTable();`

Comment: my `ddlState` remains `0` so I guess it is not null or empty

Comment: yes that is now working fine. But is it correct way to have a check like this ?

Comment: Well honestly, I don't like when `if` check becomes too big. This is now a matter how you want to break down your `if` check (and you should honestly).

Comment: Yes, I know that's  y I asked. I will change it accordingly